# Installshield throws error "New Version already present" for Minor upgrade

Tags: installshield, installshield-2018

We have one product of version 1.14.0019059. But it is not able to upgrade on 1.13.0219038. It throws error "New version is already present. Please uninstall previous version."

I am not able to understand why Installshield is not able to upgrade the product even if there is a minor version upgrade.

We are using Installshield 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/productversion states:

> The value of the ProductVersion property is the version of the product in > string format. This property is REQUIRED.
>
> The format of the string is as follows:
>
> major.minor.build
>
> The first field is the major version and has a maximum value of 255. The second field is the minor version and has a maximum value of 255. The third field is called the build version or the update version and has a maximum value of 65,535.

Comment: Issue is solved by adding -y VERSION attribute in installshield cmdline. Thanks for your input